# A question about series ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please give me some hint how to deal with this question:

Suppose $\left|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le c_n$ for each n and $c_n<1$.

May we conclude that $\left|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le c_n<1$ and by ratio test series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely ? 
Or there is counter-example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sequence $a_1 = 3$, and $a_{n+1} = a_n - \dfrac{a_n}{n}$ for $n \geq 1$ then $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1 -\dfrac{1}{n}$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = 1$. This example shows that the above convergence test can not be used since the limit of the ratio could be $1$ while the ratio test requires that it be less than $1$ for the series to be convergent.

Comment: And how could you define $c_n<1$ , please ?

Comment: Let $c_n=|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$

Comment: And why $\sum a_n$ does not converge ?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter that you have used the "intermediary variable" $c_n$. You have shown that $$|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1$$ and if this is true also for $n \to \infty$ then, by the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the series converges absolutely.